# jquery mobile - dynamic adding of radio buttons loses styling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am adding radio buttons dynamically as shown below. For some reason the styling is not applied.

Javascript/jQuery:

```
        jQuery.fn.extend({
    CE2: function (name, state, id)
    {

        var choices = ["P", "L", "A"];
        var nameLabel = document.createElement('label');
        nameLabel.innerHTML=name;
        document.getElementById('subregister').appendChild(nameLabel);
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
             var fieldset = $('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">');
            //fieldset.append( $('<legend>').html(name) );
            fieldset.append( $('<input type="radio" />').attr('name', id).attr('value', choices[i]).attr('id', id+choices[i]) );
            fieldset.append( $('<label>').attr('for', choices[i]).html(choices[i]) );
            fieldset.append('</fieldset>');
            // Radio buttons
            $('#subregister').append(fieldset);

        }
            // Set absent as default
            document.getElementById(id+state).checked = true;
    }
```

});

HTML:

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content" id="subregister">



    </div>
</div>
```

I have looked over similar questions and tried all the suggested options but I can't get it to work. For example, I tried using `.trigger("create")` and `$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");` but it did not work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that my `for` loop was all wrong. I've re-written it the 'hard way' using the info [here](http://andymatthews.net/read/2012/05/17/Dynamically-creating-jQuery-Mobile-radio-buttons-with-Mustache).

This was OK as the 'choices' were short and static. I'd love to know how to do this dynamically... I was getting the loop wrong (creating multiple fieldsets, etc). If anyone has a better solution (more flexible/dynamic) I'd love to see it.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    CE2: function (name, state, id)
    {
        var choices = ["P", "L", "A"];
        var $radios1 = $('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"></fieldset>')
                        .append(
                            $('<legend>' + name + '</legend>'),
                            $('<input />')
                                .attr({
                                    'type':'radio',
                                    'name': id,
                                    'id': id+"P",
                                    'value': 'P'
                                }),
                            $('<label />')
                                .attr({
                                    'for': id+"P"
                                }).text("P"),
                            $('<input />')
                                .attr({
                                    'type':'radio',
                                    'name': id,
                                    'id': id+"A",
                                    'value': 'A'
                                }),
                            $('<label />')
                                .attr({
                                    'for': id+"A"
                                }).text("A"),
                            $('<input />')
                                .attr({
                                    'type':'radio',
                                    'name': id,
                                    'id': id+"L",
                                    'value': 'L'
                                }),
                            $('<label />')
                                .attr({
                                    'for': id+"L"
                                }).text("L")
                        );
        $('#subregister').append($radios1).trigger('create');   

    document.getElementById(id+state).checked = true;
    $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

this work with static list, but dynamically list? Well, that is my problem, then we done this way. Using jquery mobile and not lose styling.

```
<html>
<form>
 <input type='text'>
 <!-- local to put my radios buttons -->
<div id='myDiv'>
 <!-- the radio button space -->
</div>
</form>
</html>


<script>
//indicate one div to insert radios
var divExist = $("div#myDiv");

//store all radios buttons
var radios="";

//mount the all tags
var changes = "";

//local where has one list
url = 'path/to/list/json';

$.getJSON( url, function (data) {

   //loop to get each data from the list and create the radio 
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {

        radios = radios + "<input type='radio' name='radio-choice-1' id='option-"+value.id+"' value='anyvalue'><label for='option-"+value.id+"'>"+value.id+"</label>";
}

//after mount all radios, put inside fieldset
changes = '<fieldset id="listagem" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true"> <legend class="label">Invoices</legend>'+radios+'</fieldset>';

//after put together, add on div with create
divExist.prepend(changes).trigger('create');
});
</script>
```